# 'The Android App Bundle was not signed.' when I upload my Unity project in the Play Store Console

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I've been stuck for a while now on the issue that whenever I try to upload my project (.aab file) in the Play Store, I get the 'The Android App Bundle was not signed.' error.
[image]

These are the file properties:

[image]

I also got this error and I don't know what to do with it:

[image]

And lastly, these are my build settings:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the key of the project

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you need to sign your .aab/apk, to achieve that you need to generate a Keystore and upload it to your Unity project, you can find the Keystore Manger under **Project Settings > Player > Publishing Settings**.

More info about how to sign an apk for android: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

And for information about Unity Publishing Settings: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Publishing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already did that, and it still didn't work. I uploaded a picture of it, in the question.

Comment: did you unchecked the "Development build" check on the Player Settings?